# text-align: justify; not working with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm creating PDF docs from HTML using wkhtmltopdf library. I used svg font according to this issue [wkhtmltopdf custom font letter spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908298/wkhtmltopdf-custom-font-letter-spacing)

I used a custom font, and added it by @font-face.
All works fine for me, except for `text-align: justify` is not working for some reason.

In HTML text is aligned as expected, but not in PDF.

Is anyone know how to fix this issue?

**UPD**: Added CSS and HTML example

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face{
        font-family:'source_sans_prolight';
        src: url('/font/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.svg') format('svg');
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:normal;
    }

    @font-face{
        font-family:'Source Sans Regular';
        src: url('/font/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:normal;
    }
    html, body, p, ul, li, span, img {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    body {
        font-family: "Source Sans Regular", sans-serif;
        text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    }
    .page {
        width: 729px;
    }
    .block {
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 40px;
        text-align: justify;
    }
</style>
<div class="page">
    <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque fermentum iaculis mollis. Cras in varius lectus. Mauris consequat vestibulum dolor pretium pulvinar.</div>
    <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque fermentum iaculis mollis. Cras in varius lectus. Mauris consequat vestibulum dolor pretium pulvinar.</div>
</div>
```

HTML renders as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n56PE.png

And in PDF I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhxsT.png

Comment: Show a sample of the html you're using. That will help on debugging if necessary.

Comment: @rtome done, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've tried this way, and it works for me :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);
      @font-face{
        font-family:'source_sans_prolight';
        src: url('/font/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.svg') format('svg');
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:normal;
      }

      @font-face{
        font-family:'Source Sans Regular';
        src: url('/font/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:normal;
      }
      html, body, p, ul, li, span, img {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }

      body {
        font-family: "Source Sans Regular", sans-serif;
        text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
      }
      .page {
        width: 729px;
      }
      .block {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 40px;
        text-align: justify;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque fermentum iaculis mollis. Cras in varius lectus. Mauris consequat vestibulum dolor pretium pulvinar.</div>
      <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque fermentum iaculis mollis. Cras in varius lectus. Mauris consequat vestibulum dolor pretium pulvinar.</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Since I don't have the font I've added `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);` and I just added `font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;` to your **.block** css rules.
And I added basic some tags html head body to my sample.

Give it a try. And see if it's ok that way.

Comment: This works, but the font displays not as expected. We use only SVG for generating PDF because it is provide best match to design. If I add 

    `url('/font/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/font/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),`

Then align works, and in browser are correct font, but in PDF - not. Perhaps wkhtmltopdf has some settings to this?

Comment: Can't think of any settings that might be required for this. I think you might be hitting a bug or limitation of the library. I'd advice you to turn to their mailing list and their bug tracking in github. See http://wkhtmltopdf.org/support.html . Pdf generation from html is way cool but when you want to go pixel perfect things get tough real quick. Still, see what's already logged/discussed at the wkhtmltopdf home.  Good luck !

Comment: It can be funny, but seems that there is some problems with fonts. I'll try download new ones. I'll let you know what the result. In any way - thank you for helping!

Comment: Ok, no problem. Do post what's the outcome of your effort. It'll be good to see what you get to with it.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work well for me, because font not renders in PDF correctly, so we should combine svg and woff/woff2 fonts to solve this issue. I'll accept you answer because it pushed me to combined solution. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You need to use a fix width size.

```
body {
    width: 22cm;      
    text-align: justify;
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
```

Comment: I just needed to add ```text-rendering: geometricPrecision;```.

Comment: Adding "text-rendering" worked for me too.  (I use jsoup+regex to automatically add it to  any inline element that has this in the style attribute.)